# DML not allowed on NetworkMemberGroup

Tags: apex, dml

I am trying to automate the process whereby all profiles are given access to communities.  This section when managing a community:

[image]

As I understand it, this is the [`NetworkMemberGroup`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_networkmembergroup.htm) object.  I created some code to insert new `NetworkMemberGroups`, setting the `NetworkId` to the community and the `ParentId` to the profile, but when I save the class I get the message

> DML not allowed on NetworkMemberGroup

But the docs say you can create() it, and when I go to the Workbench and check the object permissions, I get `createable` = true:

[image]

Do I need an extra permission to save the class?  Or are the docs wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all objects that you can manipulate in the API can also be modified via Apex Code. For example, [Custom Metadata](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm) can be updated by other means, but not in Apex Code. Similarly, you can't perform any DML on an [ApexClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm), even though you can manipulate code through other APIs (Tooling, Metadata). If you want to automate the process, you'll need to invent a workaround, such as calling the API via a callout.

Comment: Makes sense.  So I could call a @RemoteAction from a button in Visualforce, return the list of NetworkMemberGroups to insert, and then use AJAX to insert the list in the callback?

Comment: @GeorgeS. That, or you can do a normal synchronous call and perform the callout from Apex Code. Either way should work.